# How can I use SQL "NOT IN" Operator with Room

Tags: android, sql, android-room, android-architecture-components

```
@Query("UPDATE items SET saved=:saved WHERE id IN :itemsIds") // works
abstract void method1(List<Long> itemsIds, boolean saved);

@Query("UPDATE items SET saved=:saved WHERE id NOT IN :itemsIds") // ERROR!!
abstract void method2(List<Long> itemsIds, boolean saved);

@Transaction
void updatePreferredItems(@NonNull List<Long> prefItems) {
    method1(prefItems, true);
    method2(prefItems, false);
}
```

My objective is from an ids list I would like to to update the field *saved* of all the items to true if item id belong to ids list, false otherwise.

Why the second query is generating a compile error ?

Is this the right approach ?

Comment: Try to put parenthesis around it: `NOT IN (:itemsIds)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when you do this:

```
@Query("UPDATE items SET saved=:saved WHERE NOT(id IN :itemsIds)") // ERROR??
abstract void method2(List<Long> itemsIds, boolean saved);
```

Comment: Yes that's what I'd use in SQL, just wasn't sure how'd it work for your situation. But yes that's how I'd use Not in.